Spring Property Management with List of object
Spring Version : 6.0.4
Java : 17
I am trying to load my properties file using spring based approach.
This is my configuration class
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ConstructorBinding;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@ConfigurationProperties("test.data")
@Validated

public class MyPropertyConfiguration {

    private final String serverName;

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Users[] users;

    @ConstructorBinding
    public MWEngineConfiguration(String serverName, Users[] users) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
        this.users = users;
    }

    public String getServerName() {
        return serverName;
    }

    public Users[] getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public static class Users {

        private final String username;

        private final String password;

        @ConstructorBinding
        public Users(String username, String password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

    }

}

This is my property file:
test.data.users[0].username=user_user1
test.data.users[0].password=user_password1

test.data.users[1].username=user_user2
test.data.users[1].password=user_password2
test.data.server-name=Development

I am trying to map these property file with above Configuration class. But i can see only password is getting bind for user object not for the username.
When i comment-out password like
test.data.users[0].username=user_user1
#test.data.users[0].password=user_password1

test.data.users[1].username=user_user2
#test.data.users[1].password=user_password2

Then it bind username for object User
Can you please help me what i am doing wrong here?
I took reference from this one and it seems it is possible :
https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot
Spring @ConfigurationProperties not mapping list of objects
